# Oracle: "dirname" equivalent string function

Tags: string, oracle

Given a delimited string in Oracle, what's the most efficient way to drop the last part of the string?  If the string were delimited by "/", it would be functionally equivalent to the unix dirname command.

```
dirname /foo/bar/baz
/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
regexp_replace(your_string, '/[^/]*$')
```

P.S.: Version with `instr` and `substr` would be lengthy, but faster